# Add UITableView to a UIViewController that already displays another UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am building an app that lists Train Stations around the user's current location. On selecting a station, the app should list out the details of trains running there. But instead of navigating to a new View controller, I would like to animate in a View, which has a different UITableView, in the same original view controller. But when I try to do so, the first UITableView(the one that lists stations) is displayed in the second view. Can I load, two different UITableViews in the same UIViewController?
note:- NOT using swift

Comment: you can distinguish both the tableviews by their outlet names.

Comment: Best way to create a separate UIViewController with a UITableView, and then `[self.view addSubview:viewcontroller.view];`

Comment: Can you add code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? As others have mentioned, you can distinguish them by using outlets or tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Then you have to set your Rows according to your tableView

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if (tableView == self.tableView1){
        //Return the count you want inside self.tableView1
    }

    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
        //Return the count you want inside self.tableView2
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Finally inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath set your table Values according to your TableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
           if (tableView == self.tableView1){
              static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
              //reference the cells to the right tables
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
         }

    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
               static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
               UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
         }
    else{
        return 0;
         }
    }
```

Add your 2nd `tableView` as a subview to your `self.view`

Comment: You can use this solution, or reference your tableview with tags, it's pretty much the same.
But that will result in a lot of code in a single controller.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set tags for both `tableviews` and use this tags in `tableview` `delegate` and `datasource` method to populate data

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. Create one TableView and make two different dataSources (It's good practice to put it in a separated file). So when you need to change data, just set another dataSource and reload data.

Answer (score 0):

Create two tableViews outlets

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imgTableView: UITableView!
     @IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!
```

now here use the two different tableviews with the if-condition to assign the different data to them,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == imgTableView {
            return Array1.count
        }
        else if tableView == commentTableView {
            return Array2.count
        }
        return 1
    }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == imgTableView {
            var cell : ProductTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? ProductTableViewCell;
            var data : NSString = Array1.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString;
            cell?.configureCell(data)
            return cell!
        }
        else if tableView == commentTableView {
            var cell : CommentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CommentTableViewCell
            var data : NSDictionary = Array2.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary;
            cell.configureCell(data, cellType: CommonCellType.Products)
            return cell
        }
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    }
```